# Spring Android RestTemplate setting Timeout and TimeoutListener

Tags: android

I am using the following code in my Android application to use the RestTemplates

```
return getRestTemplate().postForObject(url, forgotPasswordRequest,
                ForgetPassword.Response.class);
```

Now how can i set the timeout for the request and use a timeout listener to catch when the request timesout ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 3):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new MyRestTemplate(10*1000);
return restTemplate.postForObject(url, forgotPasswordRequest,
            ForgetPassword.Response.class);

[...]


protected class MyRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {
    public MyRestTemplate(int timeout) {
        if (getRequestFactory() instanceof SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) {
            Log.d("HTTP", "HttpUrlConnection is used");
            ((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) getRequestFactory()).setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            ((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) getRequestFactory()).setReadTimeout(timeout);
        } else if (getRequestFactory() instanceof HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) {
            Log.d("HTTP", "HttpClient is used");
            ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) getRequestFactory()).setReadTimeout(timeout);
            ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) getRequestFactory()).setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok and how does one detect the timeout? I assume an exception is thrown?